# PHP Individual Character validation. Regex?

Tags: php, regex

Not terribly familiar with regex, but I'm guessing it's going to make life much easier for my current need.

I need to validate that a string contains the correct sequence of numbers and letters, so that it always follows the format "AA99999A", where A can be any A-Z character and 9 can be any 0-9 character. Other than exploding the string and validating the characters individually, how would the best way to handle this be?

The result can be a simple true / false as I don't need to specify which characters are incorrect

Comment: The best would be to use Regex.

Comment: And seriously - have a look and regex in php and especially `preg_match`. What you need will be fairly easy to achieve once you run through the documentation (which is very good on php.net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex:

```
'/^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$/i'
```

Comment: +1, you beat me for 13 seconds ;-).

Comment: Oh those few seconds don't matter you got it right too and deserve my +1

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match) will do the trick:

```
$string_to_be_validated = "AB12345C";
if (preg_match("/\A[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{1}\z/", $string_to_be_validated)) echo "valid";
else echo "invalid";
```

[Here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) you can find more information on this.